# How to do some action when image from firebase is stored in storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have array of url of images stored in firebase and I have used for loop for download in in mobile storage and after loop i set other method to `showImages` it in grid view. There is no problem in download but as it takes some time for download it so I want to execute `showImage` only after all images are successfully stored in mobile storage.

How can I do this task? Any help will be much helpful for me.

```
Class Images{
     string imageUrl;
     string name;

     public Images(){
     }
}
```

Here is a code for downloading images in the main activity.

```
for (Image image : imageList) {
        String url = image.getImageUrl();
        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir, i + "_" + image.getName() + ".jpg");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            StorageReference downloadRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);
            downloadRef.getFile(file).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                }
            });
            i++;
        }
    }
    showImages();
```

`showImages()` is used for showing images. But it is executed immediately after for loop and as images are bigger it takes some time for downloading.

So how can I make `showImages()` execute only after all image are downloaded successfully.

Comment: You can initialise your grid with placeholders, and when data is succesfully downloaded, replace the placeholder with real image

Comment: Please add the code that you using for getting the images.

Comment: but how can I know when the image is downloaded. By the way, I have edited my question please check it. @diouze

Comment: I have edited my question please check it. @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StorageReference's [getFile(File destinationFile)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getFile(java.io.File)) method returns a `FileDownloadTask` object which is actually a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task).

To solve you can use Tasks's [whenAllSuccess(Collection> tasks)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAllSuccess(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)) method like this:

```
List<Task<?>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
tasks.add(downloadRef.getFile(file1));
tasks.add(downloadRef.getFile(file2));
tasks.add(downloadRef.getFile(file3));
//And so on
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
        //Do what you need to do with your list
        for (Object object : list) {
            //Show images
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer but I got error `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task` because of this sentence `Tasks.whenAllSuccess((Task<?>) tasks).addOnSuccessListener` @Alex Mamo

Comment: Oh, sorry. Should be `List<Task<?>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();`. Please see my updated answer. Does it work now?